# $P=PP$ or $P=PSPACE$ vs $VP=VNP$

Tags: complexity-theory, np, complexity-classes, polynomial-time, counting

We do not know if $P=NP$ has an impact on $VP=VNP$ however how about $P=PP$?

1. Is $PP$ and $VNP$ related and would $P=PP$ or $P=PSPACE$ imply $VP=VNP$?
2. Is there a way to show $\#P$ is in $FP^{PP}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\#P\in FP^{PP}$ follows from a simple binary search. Given some non-deterministic machine $M$, the language $\{(x,k) |\#M(x)\ge k\}$, where $\#M(x)$ is the number of accepting paths on input $x$, is in PP (you can change the constant in the definition of PP to any FP function). Thus, using a PP oracle we can count the number of accepting paths via binary search.

This implies that $\mathsf{P=PP}$ puts permanent in $VP$, as the problem of counting the number of perfect matchings in a bipartite graph (or equivalently, computing the permanent of the adjacency matrix) is in $\#P$.

Comment: Is $NC^1\subsetneq L=CH$ and Permanent in $VNC^1$ a possible scenario or for Permanent to be in $NC^1$ we have to have $CH=NC^1$?